# I am getting error in setContentView

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to call another activity but I am getting error.

```
public class Type extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_types);
    }
}
```

Above is my code and in `setContentView` `activity_types` is **red**. If I remove the package name activity_types becomes normal and R becomes red.

I tried to rebuild the project and even clean the project but still I am getting the same error. In the manifest file also it is showing error in the activity tag. The error is that in the android name the class name .Type is turning red and gradle is showing to validate resource reference inside XML files.I tried to sync with gradle but still I am getting the error.

Comment: Can u post the import statement of R? Are u importing the proper R class?

Comment: post your .xml file, manifest, build error.

Answer (score 1):

Yes because you are using "Type" as name for the activity class name. 
This is prohibited just because this name class has been defined from Sdk: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/renderscript/Type.html

You just try to change the class name :)

Comment: I have created an activity with name "Type" and its not showing any errors and I have run that as well. Looks like something else is the issue mate?

Comment: @Raghavendra hmm i think there's mystery on this. With the name class "Type", the layout name usually is "activity_type" but here I see the name is "activity_types". Did he change it? I don't know what he changed else on his project.
The question seemed not clearly for others to figure out where is the problem :)

Comment: Looks like he ignored the comments. Leave it for now bro:)

Answer (score -6):

Try this.. It will work:

```
package yourPackgeName;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;



import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

public class FlashScreen extends AppCompatActivity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //hide_notification_bar
    HideNotificationBar hideNotificationBar = new    HideNotificationBar(FlashScreen.this);
    hideNotificationBar.hideNotificationBar();

    //timer
    new Timer().schedule(new TimerTask() {
        public void run() {
            startActivity(new Intent(FlashScreen.this, NewActivity.class));
        }
    }, 3000);
}
 }
```

Comment: You have neither given an explanation nor a proper solution to the problem.